# Singleton dependency with an event when subscriber does not know that it is singleton

Tags: oop, design-patterns

There is an application consisting of `UI Controller` and `Processor`. `UI Controller` receives requests from user and passes them to `Processor`. `Processor` has a simple interface: just one `Process(input)` method.

`Processor` could be a singleton or not, and `UI Controller` should not know that.

Now, `Processor` should send back some progress notifications to `UI Controller`. While I could add an event to `Processor` interface that `UI Controller` could subscribe to, I don't know how to make it work in case of a singleton `Processor`:

- subscription to the progress event should happen only once
- `Processor` should not hold references to `UI Controller` instances so that memory can be freed when needed
- progress event handlers are UI-specific, so they cannot be takes out of `UI Controller`

How would you design it so that `UI Controller` does not care whether `Processor` is singleton or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `UIController` with a reference to a `Processor` interface (constructor injection).  `UIController` doesn't know if the implementation of the interface is a singleton or not.  Change the `Processor` method to `Process(input, notifyCallback)` so `Processor` can make notifications without holding `UIController` references. `notifyCallback` will be a function or interface implemented in `UIController` (depending on language).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by having a static event in Processor class and registering it in UIController.

```
private delegate void ProgressDelegate(Processor process, object data);

class Processor
{
    public static event ProgressDelegate ProcessProgress;
    private void method()
    {
        //....your code
        if (ProcessProgress != null)
            ProcessProgress(this, new object());
    }
}
```

The event can be registered using UIController without worrying about the object. Once the event is fired, you will pass the processor object and the UIController can proceed.

```
class UIController
{
    static UIController()
    {
        Processor.ProcessProgress += new ProgressDelegate(HandleProcessProgress);
    }

    static void HandleProcessProgress(Processor p, object data)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That is essentially exposing Processor implementation and making UI Controller aware that Processor is singleton.

Comment: Static event doesn't tell the class is singleton. Even this example is not singleton. Also where do you see the implementation details have been exposed?

Comment: In your example UI Controller knows about specific Processor implementation (making UI Controller know that Processor is either singleton or not).
Making part of Processor static moves problems with singletons to that static part.

Comment: So UIController know that Processor class is either singleton or not. But it doesn't know specifically. This is how you would abstract the details.

Comment: I am not just abstracting the details of implementation, I am trying to do what you would generally do with depencency injection - making consumer not care how dependency was instantiated. Knowing if a dependency is a singleton or not breaks that.